Returning Drive Names?
I want to write code for an iOS17 Project that will be able to show me what Devices or Drives the App can physically see, like:

iCloud
Macintosh HD
USB

I am able to find a FileManager but I think this is for reading/writing files within Directories. Is this correct?
What protocol would I use to return this information as a List?

This question makes sense for macOS, but doesn't make sense for iOS. What drives does an iOS device have?

You are unable to access files on iOS due to there being no public API for the user to give apps permission to access those files and for apps to access device files. There would also be no 'Macintosh HD' folder on a iOS device because it is not a Mac.
You can request this feature here.

Thanks Knotbin,  The main system I really want to access is ‘iCloud’.  I can certainly access my iCloud through my iPad and iPhone.
What I am trying to achieve is be able to have my AppleTV access iCloud as I have  a number of files I would like to access directly.
Sorry for the confusion.

Unfortunately, that use case is not supported either.
